# SiteDataWebService.Lists' does not contain a definition for 'GetListItems'

Tags: extension-methods

I'm writing a console app to migrate Sharepoint libraries and documents from one site to a completely different site using a Sharepoint webservice (_vti_bin/Lists.asmx). In  my TRY block I am running default credentials:

```
            SiteDataWebService.Lists objLists = new SiteDataWebService.Lists();
            objLists.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            objLists.Url = "..._vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
```

I'm also using the XmlDocument and XmlNode classes to create nodes for different elements:

```
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
            XmlNode ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
            XmlNode ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");
```

In a subsequent TRY block, I am trying to use the objLists to access the GetListItems method si I can pass the library name as well as other args:

```
                XmlNode ndListItems = objLists.GetListItems("Authorizations", null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);
```

However, I am getting an error on accessing the GetListItems method:

"MigrationTool_v08.SiteDataWebService.Lists' does not contain a definition for 'GetListItems' and no extension method 'GetListItems' accepting a first argument of type 'MigrationTool_v08.SiteDataWebService.Lists' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thoughts anyone?

Thnaks so much.

Glenn